# How to insert a JSON code block for a Swagger-API using YAML?

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

In my swagger document that I am editing using YAML. I was intending to insert a Block of code using GFM syntax which is what swagger expects according to [this document](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#response-object).

````
description: >-
  Some description of the object here.
  More Here. An example to for this is as follows:
  ```json
  {
    "Key": {
      "name": "myName",
      "id": 100
    }
  }
  ```
````

This however does not show up formatted as a JSON, instead it all ends up being on one line like this:

````
Some description of the object here. More Here. An example to for this is as follows: ```json { "Key": { "name": "myName", "id": 100 } } ```
````

Comment: Try `JSON` (in all caps) as your language identifier after first set of triple backticks.  `json` (lowercase) is not a valid language on Github, so if Swagger follows that strictly, this might be a problem for you.

Answer (score 11):

That it all ends up as one line is because you are using a [folded style block scalar](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251) by specifying `>` (`-` is for stripping chomping indicator).

What you want to use is a [literal style block scalar](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688), with that the line breaks and spacing is preserved. You probably also want to use the default clip chomping (leaving one newline at the end of the JSON code):

````
description: |
  Some description of the object here.
  More Here. An example to for this is as follows:
  ```json
  {
    "Key": {
      "name": "myName",
      "id": 100
    }
  }
  ```
````

(the only change is on the first line `>-` to `|`)

Comment: Thanks for your response Anthon. I tried with the literal style block scaler before but still could not get it to work. The tabs/ deliberate spaces that I want to be seen on the Swagger API for the example JSON do not appear. Also the name json appears and so do the quotation marks surrounding the code block

Comment: tabs will not work with most YAML parsers. I don't know anything about swagger, so I cannot help you with that specific part.

Comment: Anthon response works perfectly in both swagger editor and ui. Here's a screen cap of swagger ui http://imgur.com/A835iVe